# R, bookdown package, force LaTex inside R chunk

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm writing a bookdown that should render both in HTML and PDF, so in some places i've got a chunk like:

```
{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}

if(knitr::is_html_output()) {

  cat("
      text with HTML coding, as <br> etc.
")} else {

  cat("
      \\begin{flushleft}
      left aligned text with LaTex coding, as \\break. 
      \\end{flushleft}
")}
```

Sometimes (i think) Pandoc gets it wrongly and adds \textbackslash before my LaTeX codes (i can see that in .tex file) and it goes literal.

I know a can use LaTeX chunks {=latex} in order to avoid that. But since i'm already in a R chunk, how do i force Pandoc to understand LaTeX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`knitr::raw_latex()` instead of cat() did the trick.